# Rails routes with multiple identifiers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, custom-routes

I'm trying to set up routes in Rails 3 that look like:

```
/items/:category/:name/
```

It's pretty easy to do a match to set this up, and then generate the URL with the following:

```
item_path(:category => @item.category, :name => @item.name)
```

But is there any way to set it up so that item_path @item and form_for @item will work automatically, so I don't have to pass the category every time?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more details about what is item, category, how they relate to each other and what you are doing with them.

Answer (score 0):

Not really no.  I would suggest defining a to_params (note the 's') method on Item as follows:

`def to_params
  {:category => category, :name => name}
end`

And then calling it like so `item_path(@item.to_params)`.  If you hack things to default to this I can guarantee you'll run into situations in which you don't want it.